# Pass variables from one preprocess function to another in .theme

Tags: theming, 8, status-messages

I am developing a theme in Drupal 8 and I have 2 twig files. One is `page.html.twig` and the other is `status-messages.html.twig`.

The problem is that status-messages has a variable named `message_list` (an array) but this variable is protected, so other files don't have access to it. I have tried to call this variable from `theme_preprocess_page()` like so  `$variables['testvar'] = $variables['message_list'];` with result of `$variables['testvar'] = null`.

In the next step I tried to copy the functionality of `status-messages.html.twig` from [`Drupal\Core\Render\Element\StatusMessages`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21StatusMessages.php/8.2.x) to `mythemem.theme` file, like so:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\StatusMessages;

function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // Create Dynamic path for project root elements (in general files that are in our theme project)
  $variables['theme_path'] = base_path() . $variables['directory'];

  // this here gives us the array of renderMessages() but  '#message_list' has no data in it
  $variables['testvar'] = StatusMessages::renderMessages(); 
}


function mythemem_preprocess_status_messages(&$variables) {

  // this here dose gives the value but it can be accessed  only in status-messages.html.twig
  $variables['mymessages'][] = $variables['message_list'];

  // same as in mythemem_preprocess.page
  $variables['testvar'] = StatusMessages::renderMessages(); 
}
```

My aim here is to understand how to correctly use `.theme` files, how to pass protected variables from one preprocess function to another.

---

To be more clear I would like to know/understand how to get the same effect for my `custom.html.twig` file as it is [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!status-messages.html.twig/8.2.x)

To achieve this, I want to take `$variables['message_list']` to process it as I want.

Comment: Messages are now in a block, no longer in the page template, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2446647. And you can't access the variables from the block in page directly. You render the messages by placing the block in a region and the region on the page.

Comment: @4k4 After some debugging with kint, i am sure that there is no such variable like 'message_list'

Comment: Are you trying to modify the message_list, duplicate it or move it at a specific  ?

Comment: @Cawet i am trying to duplicate this variable... but it is protected, is there a way to duplicate protected variable and pas it to the  higher level than it is right now (as i know preprocess.page function is executed before preprocess_status_messages. As level, status message is in a lower level). if i am wrong pleas correct me

Comment: @GeorgeChanturia, this is very difficult to predict what code runs in which order. One example, the message block puts only a placeholder in the page, this page gets cached, then you have a request with a cache hit for the page, no code for the page is run, but the placeholder gets replaced with the messages from the message list.

Comment: To be more clear i would like to know/understand ho to make same effect for my custom.html.twig file as it is  [link]https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!status-messages.html.twig/8.2.x) 

To achieve this, i must take thirst

$variables['message_list']
and than process it as i want...

Comment: This variable is only available in the status_messages template, so you would have to use this template to customize the messages.

Comment: OK i appreciate all your answers, i stil don't get why i cant duplicate some variables of drupal... I will stick to only drupal way stile so on...  Thanks

Comment: because it's like this!
More seriously it's because u must make change at one place and only one. If you don't, this could be very hard to remember where you did it, and it's why some var is protected

Comment: Please explain why you need to get this var, your final point. I'm sure there is some other logic to achieve what you need. This could be put it at a other place, simply altering it, or many other thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after finking a lot about this problem, i realized that i don't wont to duplicate this variable at all.

lets start from beginning i wanted to copy the `$variables['message_list']` from `status-messages.html.twig` to make my custom layout for different situation.

for example i wanted to have different layout/design of status message on  my custom login page and another layout/design for my custom register page. but now i understend that i can have this two in one place (in `status-messages.html.twig`) i can check if my URL is `/login` tean  with help of twig `if` condition i can render one layout and if  my URL is `/register` then i could have second layout! and in aver situation u would have default layout.

is that correct? how would you solve the problem if you ware in my place